# window.open() issues when already in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, window.open

Not quite sure what I'm missing but here's the issue...

I am using the following to open a new window:

```
var opts = 'location=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,height=450,width=300,right=350';
window.open('/', 'null', opts);
```

This opens a new window of 450px by 300px, positioned 300px from the right hand side of the users screen, and works great as long as the page that initiated the new window is not itself maximised/full screen when the new window is created?

So if the window that is opening the new window is in full screen mode (green plus in Mac or maximise box on Windows), it seems to completely ignore the sizing parameteres and just opens the new window as a new tab, full screen?!?

Any ideas anyone?

I know we can't prevent users resizing it after the new page has been rendered and that's fine, but I want the new window, when created, to always open at the default sizes that I have provided, in a new window.

Comment: Can you clarify? "Full Screen" is what happens when you press F11 (in windows) which is not the same thing as "Maximize".  Also, the `window.open` arguments have never been standardized and different browsers will/won't abide by what you specify. Also, for some browsers, you should be using "no", rather than "0".

Comment: If you open Chrome and press F11 in Windows, your screen will go into Full Screen mode - - the browser's tabs and borders will go away as will the Windows Taskbar. Pressing the maximize button does not remove these items. Which are you referring to?

Comment: Not the F11 full screen mode. Just the maximise options (green plus on Mac and Maximise box on Windows)

Comment: Have you tried removing all the options except `height` and `width`? I ask because when I do a `window.open()` in Chrome on Windows with the browser maximized, I get a new window that is sized correctly. The only difference is that I haven't added all those other options.

Comment: OK, so have just tried `window.open('https://google.com', '_blank', 'height=450,width=300,right=350');` in jsFiddle and hit run. If starting window is maximised, it just opens a new tab. If I come out of maximised view and hit run again, it works fine.... so getting same problem regardless of params sent - https://jsfiddle.net/ast111bk/

Comment: Don't try it in JSFiddle because the application will not run those kinds of commands exactly as they would run outside of that shell. Try it in one of your own files.

Comment: Yeh already have, I just did that to demo to you guys ;) I get the same behaviour though

Comment: Sorry, don't know what to say. It works as it should on my files. What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version:  54.0.2840.98 (64-bit) - Thanks for you help anyway mate

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this isn't an answer, but I wanted to post an image along with code.

With this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title></title>
   <script>
     window.open("http://google.com", "","width=500, height=500");
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>


 </body>
</html>
```

I get this result:

[image]

This is in Chrome 54 running on Windows. I actually teach JavaScript and have been doing this kind of exercise in my classes for years and have always gotten this same result.

I would test your code on another device to eliminate the possibility that there is a problem with your dev environment.

Comment: Hmm interesting... good to know. I'm actually on a Mac so maybe that's the difference but jeez, this is pretty basic functionality that should just carry across platforms :/

Comment: Yeah, it should, but as I said, the `window.open()` method has never been standardized.

Comment: Yeh I suppose, but standardisation is across browsers... Chrome should work the same in Mac as in Windows regardless of the standards each browser has agreed to implement, you know what I mean? OS shouldn't make a difference to browser features if the browser is the same?!

Comment: I agree, but (and this is above my pay grade) when you ask for a new Window, you are getting the OS involved. This particular issue isn't contained to the browser's environment.

Comment: Yeh I guess... I need to rethink some stuff :0 Thanks Scott, appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!